# Is there any way to install a package in all python enviroments

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda

I have created several conda environments of python. But sometimes, I encounter some utility package that can be helpful to all the environments that I have on my system. Is there any way to do this without switching back and forth between all the environments and installing them individually.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can install the package in the `base (root)` environment. All packages related with command line utilities (example `git`) and graphical user interfaces (example `spyder`) in that default environment are visibles in all your conda environments.

**Update**

You can use my [script](https://gist.github.com/cosmoscalibur/e96f053e0a3fc8301d12a9173c706831). Uncomment last 3 lines and change list of packages. You can use a manual list of envs or use automatic in all envs.

```py
import subprocess as sub

def conda_env_list():
    p = sub.Popen("conda env list", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, encoding="utf-8")
    p.wait()
    out = p.communicate()[0].splitlines()
    envs = [out[line].split()[0] for line in range(2, len(out)-1)]
    return envs

def conda_env_install(envs, packages, channel="default"):
    TEMPLATE = "conda install {confirm} -c {channel} -n {env} {packages} "
    if isinstance(envs, str):
        envs = [envs]
    if isinstance(packages, list):
        packages = " ".join(packages)
    confirm = "-y"
    for env in envs:
        cmd = TEMPLATE.format(confirm=confirm, packages=packages, \
            channel=channel, env=env)
        p = sub.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, encoding="utf-8")
        p.wait()
        print(p.communicate()[0])

envs = conda_env_list()
packages = ["git"]
conda_env_install(envs, packages)
```

Comment: I haven't tried this. But I was under the impression that base environment is disjoint with other environments in the system in terms of packages installed.

Comment: You are partially true. Not all packages are visible through environments. Packages that are GUI or command utilities work but libs or modules not (I have tested that). For example, git and spyder are available but not numpy.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to identify whether a package is just a utility or library. I am sort sure of how to distinguish between command utility vs modules. For example, https://github.com/transcranial/jupyter-themer works by changing theme of the notebooks using command line. So can this be a command line utility ?

Comment: Yes, `jupyter-themer` works. You can identify that because you know what is the package. In this case, you can execute using a command line in your console (command line utility).

Comment: Thanks. I will wait for a week to check for any other answers and will close with this answer as the best one if not.

Comment: @RTM I have added a link to my gist with a script that help to install conda packages in all envs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this script over the last two weeks installing several packages and it works without any errors :D

Answer (score 0):

If you store all you virtual environments in one place or if you already use `virtualenvwrapper` that stores virtualenv in `~/.virtualenvs/` you can use command `allvirtualenv` from  `virtualenvwrapper`; if you don't use  `virtualenvwrapper` you have to install it first.

```
allvirtualenv pip install somepackages
```

I use the following bash script to run a command over all environments in `~/.virtualenvs/` and in`~/.tox/`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if source virtualenvwrapper.sh; then
   allvirtualenv eval "$@"

   for tox_envs in ~/.tox/*; do
      if [[ "$tox_envs" = */.tox/\* ]]; then
         exit 0
      fi
      WORKON_HOME="$tox_envs" allvirtualenv eval "$@"
   done
fi
```